# How to insert JSON into cassandra database using C language

Tags: sql, c, cassandra

how i can insert/select JSON data into/from a table in Cassandra using C language .
In other words I used Embedded SQL statements to do this .
but know I need to apply this approach which explained in this article . https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inserting-json-data-into-a-table-in-cassandra/
but using C language .
is it possible to this ? and any helpful article about the topic.

Answer (score 0):

There's no C driver for Cassandra but there's a [C++ driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/cpp-driver/latest).

For the list of drivers from DataStax, see the [DataStax drivers for Apache Cassandra](https://docs.datastax.com/en/driver-matrix/doc/driver_matrix/common/driverMatrix.html). Cheers!